# Estimating truncation point in Gaussian mixture

Tags: bayesian, normal-distribution, expectation-maximization, gaussian-mixture-distribution

I have data modeled as a mixture of two Gaussian distributions. The data is "clipped" i.e., there is data only for values greater than a threshold $t$, even though it is feasible for data to exist in the range $(-\inf, t]$. How can I estimate the probability distribution of $t$, given the data?

Comment: You should use a mixture of folded normal distributions

Comment: I'm looking for the probability distribution of $t$, the point beyond which there is no data, as opposed to fitting the data to a model.

Comment: If you are able to write an estimation algorithm for  a Bayesian model, then it is pretty simple. But the solution will be something really concentrated close to the smaller observation

Comment: it is unclear whether or not the number of censored datapoints is known.

Comment: Can you specify whether or not you know the number of observations less than $t$?

Comment: No, I don't know the number of observations less than $t$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are (at least) two possible models associated with this question:

1. A truncated Gaussian mixture$$p{\cal N}^+(\mu_1,\sigma_1,t)+(1-p){\cal N}^+(\mu_2,\sigma_2,t)$$where $t$ is the truncation point and ${\cal N}^+(\mu_2,\sigma_2,t)$ denote the truncated Normal distribution with density $\sigma_1^{-1}\varphi(\sigma_1^{-1}[x-\mu_1])\Phi^{-1}(\sigma_1^{-1}[\mu_1-t])$
2. A censored Gaussian mixture$$p{\cal N}(\mu_1,\sigma_1)+(1-p){\cal N}(\mu_2,\sigma_2)$$where all $n_t$ observations less than $t$ are not observed (but accounted for). If $n_t$ is unknown, this model is equivalent to the first one.

If we adopt a Bayesian approach with a prior $\pi(\theta)$ on the parameter $\theta=(\mu_1,\mu_2,\sigma_1,\sigma_2,p,t)$, a Gibbs sampler can be constructed by

1. allocating the observations $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ to either component with probabilities $$p\sigma_1^{-1}\varphi(\sigma_1^{-1}[x_i-\mu_1])\Phi^{-1}(\sigma_1^{-1}[\mu_1-t])$$ and $$(1-p)\sigma_2^{-1}\varphi(\sigma_2^{-2}[x_i-\mu_2])\Phi^{-1}(\sigma_2^{-1}[\mu_2-t])$$ (up to a constant), thus creating a latent vector $(z_1,\ldots,z_n)$;
2. simulating $(\mu_1,\mu_2,\sigma_1,\sigma_2,p)$ conditional on $t$,$(z_1,\ldots,z_n)$ and $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ (which may involve a Metropolis-Hastings step);
3. simulating $t$ conditional on everything else, which involves a Metropolis-Hastings step.

In the case of the censored mixture (#2), the $n_t$ censored observations are also to be simulated on step 1.